# How to end a call in CallKit

Tags: ios, callkit

This is not a give-me-code question, this is a feasibility question. If I initiate a phone call using CallKit, is it also possible to programmatically end it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, we can do programmatically, but we have to keep the UUID for that call,

```
CXEndCallAction *endaction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID];
[cxcallcontrollerobject requestTransaction:[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:@[action]] completion:completion];


    + (CXTransaction *)transactionWithActions:(NSArray <CXAction *> *)actions { 
        CXTransaction *transcation = [[CXTransaction alloc] init]; 
        for (CXAction *action in actions) { 
           [transcation addAction:action]; 
        } 
        return transcation; 
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting error code 4 , it means invalid UUID. i am passing same UUID which i have used while establish call.

Comment: how the uuid has been stored? NSUserDefaults or some other way. Did you convert that into integer?(just for clarification)

Comment: No i am taking it as global variable in appDelegate

Comment: if you are generating the uuid, check the uuid is generated or not. Even we faced the uuid becomes nil sometimes.

Comment: I have checked that UUID is not nil & is generated Successfully.

Comment: @RJVKumar what is "callUUID".. From where i get callUUID ?

Comment: @VarinderSingh UUID is the identifier for that particular call. You can get when you are initiating the call.

Comment: Error Getting. No known class method for selector 'transactionWithActions'

Comment: @VarinderSingh + (CXTransaction *)transactionWithActions:(NSArray <CXAction *> *)actions {
    CXTransaction *transcation = [[CXTransaction alloc] init];
    for (CXAction *action in actions) {
        [transcation addAction:action];
    }
    return transcation;
}

Comment: @RJVKumar Do you know what I need to import to get rid of those two errors?: "Use of undeclared identifier 'cxcallcontrollerobject'" and "Use of undeclared identifier 'transactionWithActions'"

Answer (score 8):

Close All Call (Swift4)

```
func endCall(call: UUID) {

    let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: call)
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endCallAction)
    cxCallController.request(transaction) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("EndCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription).")
            self.cxCallProvider.reportCall(with: call, endedAt: Date(), reason: .remoteEnded)
            return
        }

        print("EndCallAction transaction request successful")

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey
the reportCall method doesn't seem to dismiss the CallKit UI, it worked for you?

Comment: @vivektakrani  

    guard let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "CallId") else {
    return
    }
 
    self.cxCallProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, endedAt: Date(), reason: .remoteEnded)

Comment: Note: without the reportCall method the status bar's color's change might have an unintented delay.

Answer (score 4):

In swift use the following code, uuidCallKit is the UUID of the current call that I'm having with me.

```
let controller = CXCallController()
let transaction = CXTransaction(action: 
CXEndCallAction(call: uuidCallKit))controller.request(transaction,completion: { error in })
```

Comment: Straight forward answer that does the job. Thanks!