# disconnect call in Ringing State Callkit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, callkit

How to disconnect call in CallKit, when a call is in the Ringing state? I am using below code for disconnect callKit Call.

This code is working when I Disconnect call after Accept. but when a call is in the Ringing state then this code is not working. call keep Ringing.

I have checked  that UUID is not nil .

Please let me know what is the proper way to do this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallController *callKitCallController;

- (void)performEndCallActionWithUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid {
    if (uuid == nil) {
        return;
    } 
    CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:uuid];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];
    [self.callKitCallController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"EndCallAction transaction request failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"EndCallAction transaction request successful");
        }
    }];
}
```

I have tried this link also ->. [Callkit Call End](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489194/4970453)

i am getting this error..please check screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your class,

```
+ (CXTransaction *)transactionWithActions:(NSArray <CXAction *> *)actions {
```

`CXTransaction *transcation = [[CXTransaction alloc] init];`

```
for (CXAction *action in actions) { 

[transcation addAction:action]; 

}
 return transcation;
}
```